# Button.getBackground() returns ShapeDrawble or what?

Tags: java, button, casting

I have a button which loads a < shape > XML resource @drawable/rectangle_shape.xml for its background. Then , I try to get the button background with codes like this :

```
ShapeDrawable rectangle = (ShapeDrawable)button.getBackground();
```

However, I have a runtime error which states that it can't cast the Drawable, returned by `getBackground()`, to ShapeDrawable.

I found this strange because, as I learned, ShapeDrawable is used to create shapes programmatically.

Then I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066892/how-to-import-shape-resourcexml-to-code) by Roman Nurik, he said `<shape>` XML resource map to GradientDrawble. I have tried this, it's true.

My question is :

How can we know  `Button.getBackground()` cast `<shape>` XML resource to GradientDrawble. Where can I get this information?

Many thanks!